# AsyncFileUpload and GridView

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I've a little problem.
I have in the same page an AsyncFileUpload and a gridview.
How do I update this gridview immediatly after it has been done upload with AsyncFileUpload?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that i am using, maybe there are better ones but at least it's working:

On your aspx page create a div like:

```
<div style="visibility: hidden;">
   <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" OnClick="btnHidden_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

On your AsyncFileUpload's **OnUploadedComplete** event write a code that stores the needed informations about the uploaded file in Session variables (since AsyncFileUpload dont have a viewstate).

On your AsyncFileUpload's **OnClientUploadComplete** place a **Javascript** function that click's the hidden button and in the codebehind the hidden button's click method is binding your gridview and clearing the session. Thats all! :)

ps.: wrap around your gridview with an updatepanel and your page wont blink